# BlackBerry - SVG (JSR 226) or OpenGL ES (JSR 239) charting library

Tags: blackberry, charts, opengl-es, svg, graph

Does anyone know of a library to display charts and graphs natively on blackberry devices ? There are quite a few javascript (Flot...) charting libraries but I'd rather use something similar to Coreplot on iPhone if it is possible. I didn't find anything on top of SVG (JSR 226) or open GL ES (JSR 239) so any help is appreciated.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to:

- draw Bar Charts (both vertical and
  horizontal)
- draw Stacked bar charts
- draw Pie charts
- drill-down one level on each bar or
  pie section to get corresponding
  information

Comment: Hi! Is this http://code.google.com/p/flot/ you have mentioned? If yes is it working with Blackberry browser/browserfield?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Max. This the Flot I was referring to but I was looking into directly using SVG charting libraries (or open GL) if there are any to get a better looking UI. If things come to worse, I'll go ahead and code that myself but I thought that someone must have tried to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Initially we have tried creating reporting graphs using OPENGL and also have searched for other third party libraries but as like you, it was of no use for us too

We have used the graphics object of the paint method to draw each graphs(pie bar both vertical and horizontal) 
pie is drawn using the fillarc() method and bar by the drawline()
you can also drill down each section of a pie chart using our coordinate geometry

for example - if you are using touch mobiles get the pixel of the touch points calculate the slope between the touch points and center and distance if it satisfies increase the radius of the sector(arc).